# How to embed a python dash app to a HTML webpage

Tags: html, plotly-dash, dashboard

Am looking for an example where people have tried embedding Dash app to an existing HTML/CS without letting the Dash app running. Ideally, the dash app should be triggered from within the HTML page. Something better than https://dash.plotly.com/integrating-dash which seems to expect the dash app to run in the background and connect the dash app URL.

Comment: If you need actual Python callbacks, the only solution I have seen so far is WebDash. But it is pretty alpha. https://github.com/ibdafna/webdash

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Emher, we managed to get the dash app embedded into a pre-made HTML page by parsing iframe (src = ) :

1. we had a flask that runs the companies wireframe written in CSS & HTML.
2. used 'server' parameter to piggyback on flask
3. added one iframe (src = Dash app) to the HTML layout for each data science dash app we have.

Will check out 'webdash' as well for creating lightweight POC

Comment: Can you send me an example code on how you did it? because I have the same problem and I want to imbed my data science apps on the company website. Thanks